# UICollectionView Not Displaying A Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

Preface: The iPad layout for my application requires a cell ("PostAddCell") to be rendered within the collection view at the start of the items ("PostCell") which are provided by an NSFetchedResultsController.  This cell functions as a button for creating a new item.  On the iPhone this isn't necessary as there a UI button for adding a new post.

Problem: The PostAddCell only appears when the NSFetchedResultsController has no results. If the fetch returns 7, all I see are the 7 PostCells even though breakpoints and logging suggests a PostAddCell is being returned by the datasource for index path 0:0

```
#pragma mark - UICollectionView Datasource

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [_fetch sections][section];
    if(isPad()){
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects]+1;
    }else{
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return [[_fetch sections] count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell;

    if(isPad()){
        if(indexPath.row == 0){
            cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PostAddCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            [(MNPAddPostCell*)cell configure];
        }else{
            NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row-1 inSection:indexPath.section];
            cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PostCell" forIndexPath:newIndexPath];
            [(MNPPostCell*)cell configureForPost:[_fetch objectAtIndexPath:newIndexPath]];
        }
    }else{
        cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PostCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [(MNPPostCell*)cell configureForPost:[_fetch objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
    }

    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of issues here I think. First, perhaps you should be checking the index path section as well as the index path row unless you want an MNPAddPostCell at row 0 in every section, assuming there is more than one section? Secondly I think

```
cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PostCell" forIndexPath:newIndexPath];
```

may be stomping your MNPAddPostCell. Shouldn't it be

```
cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PostCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

and just use your new index path to get the right object from the controller?

Comment: I will want an MNPAddPostCell at row 0 in every section.  I don't understand how a PostCell would ever stomp on a PostAddCell identifier.  The outer block is for iPad and the else.  The inner is the row check for iPad only and newIndexPath is created to ensure the cell creation doesn't try to access a row that doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, the indexPath you of the new cell you return for cellForItemAtIndexPath for row 1 will be for row 0, so I wonder if the UITableView uses that rather than the indexPath it passed originally, that's what I meant by stomping the PostAddCell.

Comment: s/UITableView/UICollectionView :)